# how to split and save

Tags: c, split, strtok

my problem is next:

```
char str[25] = "exsample=string=to=split";
char a[2] = "=";
char* token;
token = strtok(str, a);
```

as you know that code saves first part `"exsample"` to string `token`

but how I can take next part of line? meaning `string` and all after it `to` `split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `token = strtok( NULL, a );`

But you should consider using thread safe `strtok_r()` instead of `strtok()`. [The man page for both functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) includes a good example.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for `strtok`:

> `str`
> ...
>   Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

In other words:

```
nextToken = strtok(NULL, a);
```